# How to fix AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute when data has blank cells

Tags: python-2.7, cx-oracle, nonetype

Can someone help, the below code fell over & produced a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strftime'.

I've checked the data & some blank cells have now appeared in the Cols 5 that have never been there before.

Is there a simple fix I could do to the below script?

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('User','PassWord,'adhoc_serv')
cursor = connection.cursor()
SQL="SELECT * FROM CAT34"
cursor.execute(SQL)
filename = r"C:\Projects\CAT34\SQL_Export\CAT34.csv"

with open(filename, "wb") as fout:
writer = csv.writer(fout)
writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cursor.description ]) # heading row

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    cols = list(row)
    cols[2] = cols[2].strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    cols[5] = cols[5].strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    writer.writerow(cols)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cx_Oracle returns None when the value being retrieved is null. If you want to avoid that, you can do something like this instead:

```
cols[2] = cols[2] and cols[2].strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

That will give you a None (when the value is null) or the date encoded as a string if it is not null.

If you want to have a "" instead of None you can do this

```
cols[2] = cols[2] and cols[2].strftime("%d/%m/%Y") or ""
```

One final option: you can simply adjust your query so that it does this instead:

```
select to_char(datecol1, 'dd/mm/YYYY') from CAT34;
```

This will return the date as a string instead of as a date value.

Hopefully one of those options will give you what you are looking for!